# Ubuntu 16.04 | Can't log back in from suspend after kernel update using GNOME 3 (NVIDIA)

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, gnome, kernel, login

Recently I upgraded the kernel I was using to the newest available, and everything worked great until the screen locked and I couldn't log back in. At first it was a black screen displaying the top bar with the clock and user name, now it's like the desktop froze even though I still can move my cursor.
Reading all the questions asked here and trying all of the solutions provided the only way I could get back was rebooting (logging through <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>)

I have tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` changing between GDM and LightDM.
And I tried `sudo chown user:user .Xauthority`.

I also tried reinstalling GDM and disabling and/or upgrading the *nvidia* drivers, as I read that that could have been the problem.*

**kernel**: *4.13.8-041308-generic*
**shell**: *Gnome 3.18.5*
**distro**: *Ubuntu 16.04*

**Edit: *Just playing around with nvidia releases I discovered that `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` solved the problem but it brought other problems as well.**

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution I was hoping for. Either way... I had to downgrade my kernel to 4.4. At the time I didn't know that installing newer versions, (not stable, mainline? I don't really know), were to crash especially drivers concerning graphics. So as a matter of fact it was a problem with Nvidia and after trying different versions of the same driver I decided, since nothing much changed since my kernel update, I should maybe go back to the old, stable one.

How I changed the kernel:
https://askubuntu.com/a/142000/742966

And removing the "newer" one was a matter of `sudo apt-get remove linux-image-4.13.8-041308-generic` and `sudo update-grub`